# Creating a circular View Pager but when switching from last page to first then it flickers

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Firstly this is not a duplicate question as i have checked all round but nothing found related to this.

Now what i'm facing is : I'm trying to make a circular view pager. What i have done is :

1. Used a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as I'm dealing with `Fragments` in View pager.

everything is working fine but when I switch from last page to first or from first page to last on click of previous or next button in my layout then view pager flickers a bit. i.e it does not goes like normal as I'm switching between pages normally.

I've done this  `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0,false);` when going from last to first page. And `viewPager.setCurrentItem(mList.size()-1,false);` when switching from first to last page..

Here is my code snippet

```
    nextimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1>=mList.size()){
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0,false);  
            }else{
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);
            }

        }
    });

    previmg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1<0){
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(mList.size()-1,false); 
            }else{
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true);

            }
        }
    });
```

**Adapter** :

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<Model> mList) {
        super(fm);
        this.mList=mList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {


       return mList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {     
        Fragment mDetail=new DetailResultFragment(mList);
        return  mDetail; 
    }
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions to avoid this flickering.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve it, but I think I know why the flickering is  happening. When you are on the second page, page 1 and 3 are also loaded into memory. However, when you're on page 1, the last page isn't loaded yet, which means that when you go from 1 to the last page, that page still needs to be loaded into memory. This could cause your flicker. When you go from 2 to 1 for example, this wuoldn't happen since page 1 was already loaded into memory earlier. Not sure if this is what's happening though, just an educated guess.

Comment: actually view pager creates 2 page at a time as i know .. and when we change page next two are added and so on. so thing is when i move from index 10 to directly 1 it flickers as compared to normal smoothscroll. as you can see i have set smoothscroll false because if set true then all the pages forward or backward will be shown one by one depending as i am going towards first or last. . don't know yet how to tackle this

Comment: @kamalvaid: I am facing the same issue. any workaround?